# Fluent NHibernate not auto-mapping one-to-many property in base class

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

Let's say I have an abstract base class defined as follows:

```
public abstract class CompanyBase : EntityBase<CompanyBase>
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual StreetAddress Address { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Then I create several other classes that derive from this class, like this:

```
public class CustomerCompany : CompanyBase
{
    // Properties relevant to a customer
}

public class VendorCompany : CompanyBase
{
    // Properties relevant to a vendor
}
```

Each derived class has its own table — in this example **CustomerCompany** and **VendorCompany**. There is no **CompanyBase** table.

I set up auto-mapping via Fluent NHibernate, ignoring the base classes, and everything works great *except* for the `PhoneNumbers` property. It doesn't show up in the hbm file when exported, and it doesn't get pulled from the database. It seems like it's just overlooking that property. If I put the `PhoneNumbers` property on the derived class, everything works great.

I haven't been able to find anything on the internet related to this...has anyone seen this? Is there a way to work around it or do I have to move the `PhoneNumbers` declaration out to the derived classes (and end up with a lot of duplication)?

**Update:**
I accepted the override answer below, but still maintain that automapping should account for collections without overrides. What I ended up doing to solve this particular issue was go to a single discriminated table rather than a table-per-subclass. Doing so allowed things to automap correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always override the convention. Auto-mapping is very particular, and can only detect what it already knows to look for and what you additionally tell it:

```
mappings
   .Override<CustomerCompany>(m=>m.HasMany(x=>x.PhoneNumbers))
   .Override<VendorCompany>(m=>m.HasMany(x=>x.PhoneNumbers));
```

Adding this to your automapping config should have it follow as many conventions as it can, but also do as specifically told.

Comment: Is auto-mapping a collection in a base class *supposed* to be supported? I hate to have to work around with overrides since I've already got a series of conventions set up to handle cascades, etc. Wouldn't I have to explicitly duplicate those one-to-many conventions on every override?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try...

Change the type of PhoneNumbers from IEnumerable to IList.  I would then expect all your derived classes to inherit the list, without any need for conventions or overrides.

I know from experience that IList is well supported by FNH Automapping - not so sure about IEnumerable.